# Find directories that do not contain subdirectories

Tags: shell, find, directory, ls, ksh

I'm writing script is ksh. Need to find all directory names directly under the current directory which contain only files, not subdirectories.

I know that I could use `ls -alR` and recursively parse output for the first letter in the first field (`d` for a directory). I think `awk` is the best way to parse and find.

For example, a simple `ls -al` output in the current directory:

```
   drwxr-xr-x  22 af      staff    748 18 Mar 22:21 .
   drwxr-xr-x   5 root    admin    170 17 Mar 18:03 ..
   -rw-------   1 af      staff      3 17 Mar 16:37 .CFUserTextEncoding
   drwxr-xr-x   5 af      staff    170 17 Mar 17:12 Public
   drwxr-xr-x   9 af      staff    306 18 Mar 17:40 Sites
   -rw-------   1 af      staff      3 17 Mar 16:37 textd
   …
```

There are 2 directories in this output: `Public` and `Sites`. The directory `Public` doesn't contain subdirectories, but `Sites` does. There are 3 subdirectories in `Sites`. So I need to echo only the directories which don't contain directories in them. In my case, this is only `Sites`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `awk` at all.  Use the built-in tests that `ksh` provides, something like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

for NAME in *
do
    FOUND=no
    if [[ -d $NAME && $NAME != '.' && $NAME != '..' ]]
    then
        for SUBNAME in $NAME/*
        do
            if [[ -d $SUBNAME ]]
            then
                FOUND=yes
                break
            fi
        done
        if [[ $FOUND == no ]]
        then
            echo Found only files in $NAME
        fi
    fi
done
```

That little script looks in all the directories in the current directory, and tells you if they only contain files, no sub-directories.

Answer (score 23):

If you are able to use `find` and if you are working on a "normal Unix filesystem" (that is, as defined in [find(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) under *-noleaf* option description), then the following command can be used:

```
find . -type d -links 2
```

Each directory has at least 2 names (hard links): `.` and its name. Its subdirectories, if any, will have a `..` pointing to the parent directory, so a directory with N subdirectories will have hard link count equal to N+2. Thus, searching for directories with hard link count equal to 2, we search for directories with N=0 subdirectories.

So, if you can use `find`, this is arguably the fastest method and obviously superior to in-shell loops over the directory contents `stat()`'ing each of its members.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the directory contains any files.

Comment: It's not about entries in the directory listing, it's about hard links referring to the directory's inode. For example, if `/some/directory` has inode #12345678, if it has no sub-directories, there will be exactly 2 hard links to that inode: `/some/directory/.` and `/some/directory`. 
It works whether or not there are any files in the directory.

Comment: Worth mentioning that BTRFS is not a "normal Unix filesystem" in this respect: directories always have a link count of 1, unfortunately.  (But `.` and `foo/..` do have the same inode number.)

Answer (score 4):

`*/` matches the subdirectories of the current directory. This includes symbolic links to directories, which you may or may not desire.

In ksh93, adding `~(N)` at the beginning of the pattern makes it expand to the empty list if there is no match. Without this, the pattern remains unchanged if there is no match.

The following ksh93 function lists the subdirectories of the current directories that do not contain any subdirectory or link to a directory.

```
list_leaf_directories () {
  local FIGNORE='.?(.)'        # don't ignore dot files
  local d
  for d in */; do
    [[ -L $d ]] || continue;   # skip symbolic links
    set -- ~(N)"$d"/*/
    if ((!$#)); then echo "$d"; fi
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am the current author of *rawhide* (*rh*) (see https://github.com/raforg/rawhide).

In [How to find only directories without subdirectories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497185/how-to-find-only-directories-without-subdirectories) there is a solution that works on
btrfs, but it's very complicated:

```
find . -type d \
    \( -exec sh -c 'find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | grep -cz "^" >/dev/null 2>&1' _ {} \; -o -print \)
```

There's an alternative to *find* called *rawhide* (*rh*) that makes this much easier:

```
rh 'd && "[ $(rh -red -- %S | wc -l) = 0 ]".sh'
```

A slightly shorter/faster version is:

```
rh 'd && "[ -z \"$(rh -red -- %S)\" ]".sh'
```

The above commands search for directories and then list their sub-directories and only match when there are none (the first by counting the number of lines of output, and the second by checking if there is any output at all per directory).

If you don't need support for btrfs, it's more like *find* but still shorter:

```
rh 'd && nlink == 2'
```

For a version that works on all filesystems as efficiently as possible:

```
rh 'd && (nlink == 2 || nlink == 1 && "[ -z \"$(rh -red -- %S)\" ]".sh)'
```

On normal (non-btrfs) filesystems, this will work without the need for any additional processes for each directory, but on btrfs, it will need them. This is probably best if you have a mix of different filesystems including btrfs.

Comment: Looks interesting.  Can it use ``$(…)`` rather than `\`…\``?

Comment: Yes. The "cmd".sh construct contains any arbitrary /bin/sh command. It is not limited. I just used `` because it's a character shorter.

Comment: I've changed all the backticks to `$(...)` becsuse it's safer.

Answer (score 0):

if I am not misunderstanding you, you only want to find files in the directory not the subdirectories. If this is your intention, here is the solution

```
find . -type f
```

if you want to find other than regular files (like block device files, character device files etc) then see the man page for `find` command and look for the *type* keyword on that page. You will see different filetypes, including regular files and directories etc.

Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: No, that's not the question at all. It's reasonably clear once you s/catalogue/directory/g. Nat Kup is looking for directories that don't contain subdirectories.