# How to find only directories without subdirectories?

Tags: linux, shell-script, find, ls, directory-structure

Is there a way in linux to look through a directory tree for only those directories that are the ends of branches (I will call them leaves here), i.e., dircetories with no subdirectories in them? I looked at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68577) but it was never properly answered.

So if I have a directory tree

```
root/
├── branch1
│   ├── branch11
│   │   └── branch111   *
│   └── branch12        *
└── branch2
    ├── branch21        *
    └── branch22
        └── branch221   *
```

can I find only the directories that are the end of their branch (the ones marked with`*`), so looking only at the number of directories, not at the number of files? In my real case I am looking for the ones with files, but they're a subset of the 'leaves' that I want to find in this example.

Comment: please clarify: "no matter how many files they contain"  vs " I am looking for the ones with files"

Comment: Sorry. That comment was because of the previous post, where the answer with the most votes looked for *empty* directories vs directories with subdirectories.

Comment: so you explicitly want to look for not (!) empty directories ? Then you should accept Bodo's answer.

Comment: No, I mean that I am looking for directories that don't contain subdirectories, irrespective of whether or not they contain files.

Comment: but isn't that exactly what the most upvoted answer from your linked question does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find directories that do not contain subdirectories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68577/find-directories-that-do-not-contain-subdirectories).  The `find -type d -links 2` answer on the other question *does* do exactly what you want (unless you're using BTRFS); read more carefully or actually try it.  Or maybe we should close that as a duplicate of this.

Comment: You're right. I tested this by putting a file in all directories: `for f in $(find root -type d);do cd $f;touch test.txt;cd /tmp;done` and then the `find` answer works. The accepted answer returns nothing.

Comment: SO "do not recommend deleting questions with answers" -- not sure what to do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To find only those leaf directories that contain non-directory files, you can combine an answer of the referenced question https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203991/330217 or similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269862/10622916 or https://serverfault.com/a/530328 with `find`'s `! -empty`

```
find rootdir -type d -links 2 ! -empty
```

Checking the hard links with `-links 2` should work for traditional UNIX file systems. The `-empty` condition is not part of the POSIX standard, but should be available on most Linux systems.

According to KamilMaciorowski's comment the traditional link count semantics for directories is not valid for Btrfs. This is confirmed in https://linux-btrfs.vger.kernel.narkive.com/oAoDX89D/btrfs-st-nlink-for-directories which also mentions Mac OS HFS+ as an exception from the traditional behavior. For these file systems a different method is necessary to check for leaf directories.

Comment: In Btrfs any directory reports link count of 1. I guess it's not a "normal UNIX file system" then…

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for the hint. I added a paragraph about exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

You could use nested `find` and count number of subdirectories:

```
find . -type d \
  \( -exec sh -c 'find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | grep -cz "^" >/dev/null 2>&1' _ {} \; -o -print \)
```

Comment: Tested on BTRFS, yes this works without relying on link-count=2.  But it's *not* fast or efficient.  It spawns `sh` to run a pipeline for every directory (empty or not) in the tree.

Answer (score 5):

With `zsh`:

```
leafdirs=( **/*(NDFl2) )
```

Sets the `$leafdirs` array with the list of matching leaf directories.

You can `print` the list `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn with:

```
print -rC1 -- $leafdirs
```

Or loop over them with:

```
for dir ($leafdirs) something with $dir
```

That's more or less a translation of [@Bodo's GNU `find` answer](/a/497195), so like it works only on traditional Unix-like file systems like `ext4` that implement `.` and `..` as actual directory entries.

- `**/`: any level of subdirectories
- `(NDFl2)`: glob qualifier
- `N`: enable `nullglob` for that one glob: don't fail if there's no match. Instead, result in an empty list
- `D`: enable `dotglob` for that one glob: look inside hidden dirs, and don't skip hidden files
- `F`: select *full* directories: directories containing at least one entry other than `.` and `..` (like GNU `find`'s `-type d ! -empty`)
- `l2`: only dirs with a link count of 2 (like `-links 2`). One for the dir's entry in its parent directory and one for `.` in it. Any subdir would add one to the link count because of the `..` entry in those.

On file systems where nlinks == 2 cannot be used, you could do:

```
leafdirs=( **/*(NDF^e['()(($#)) $REPLY/*(ND/Y1)']) )
```

Where we use the `e` qualifier (negated with `^`) to run the code that checks whether the directory (stored in `$REPLY` in that code) has subdirectories, here using an anonymous function to check whether the expansion of `$REPLY/*(ND/Y1)`, the directories in `$REPLY`, stopping at the first match, passed as its arguments is a non-empty list (`$#` is non-zero).

Answer (score 4):

If the `*/` filename globbing pattern expands to something that is not the name of a directory, then the current directory has no (non-hidden) subdirectories.

With `find`:

```
find root -type d -exec sh -c 'set -- "$1"/*/; [ ! -d "$1" ]' sh {} \; ! -empty -print
```

Note that this would treat a symbolic link to a directory in a leaf directory as a directory since the pattern would traverse the symbolic link.

The `-empty` predicate is not standard, but often implemented.  Without it, you would do something similar as with detecting subdirectories:

```
find root -type d \
    -exec sh -c 'set -- "$1"/*/; [ ! -d "$1" ]' sh {} \; \
    -exec sh -c 'set -- "$1"/*;  [   -e "$1" ]' sh {} \; -print
```

Or, a bit more efficiently,

```
find root -type d -exec sh -c '
    dir=$1
    set -- "$dir"/*/
    [ -d "$1" ] && exit 1
    set -- "$dir"/*
    [ -e "$1" ]' sh {} \; -print
```

Or, employing the `-links` predicate that I had forgotten about ([thanks Bodo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/497195/116858)):

```
find root -type d \
    -links 2 \
    -exec sh -c 'set -- "$1"/*; [ -e "$1" ]' sh {} \; -print
```