# Linux find <DOCKER_MOUNTED_DIR> -type d: how to list the deepest dirs, such as ./dir1/dir2 without ./dir1?

Tags: find

```
find . -type d
```

normally will show

```
./dir1
./dir1/dir2
./dir3
./dir3/dir4
./dir3/dir4/dir5
...
```

I just want the

```
./dir1/dir2
./dir3/dir4/dir5
```

, without its parent ./dir1, ...

In other words, I only want to see directories that does not have any subdirectories in them.

Any idea?

EDIT: I found the `-links 2` does work in a normal linux environment, e.g.,

```
docker run -it --rm ubuntu:bionic find /etc -type d -links 2
```

works perfectly.

However, when I mount a dir (from MacOS or Windows) into the docker container, things changed, it does not work, you can try this:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /etc:/etc_of_host ubuntu:bionic find /etc_of_host -type d -links 2
```

Comment: In other words, you only want to see directories that does not have any subdirectories in them?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen exactly

Comment: So you need a command that tells how many subdiredtories a directory has, and apply that to all directories found, and only print those with a value of 0?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen in some meaning, it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find only directories without subdirectories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497185/how-to-find-only-directories-without-subdirectories)

Comment: @muru thank you, but neither works perfectly.

Comment: Finally I found a trivial modified version works for me (on a Linux container), `find . -type d -links 2 -noleaf`

Comment: For docker mounted dir `find . -type d -links 3` works, but this is really not reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sortest:

```bsh
p="";(find . -type d;echo) | while read d; do [[ $p && $d != $p/* ]] && echo $p; p=$d; done
```

In one line

```bsh
a="";(find . -type d;echo )|while read i; do if  [[ (! $i =~ $a) && ("$a" != "") ]]; then echo $a; fi; a=$i;done
```

As the op mentioned:

```bsh
a="";(find . -type d;echo )|while read i; do [[ $i != $a/* && ! -z "$a" ]] && echo $a; a=$i;done
```

Comment: You may want to read [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: Note that every shell script can be put on one line. That rarely make them more legible.

Comment: `[[ $i =~ $a ]]` checks whether `$i` matches the regular expression in `$a`, I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: thank you.  this works. If no any other simpler method, this is the final resort.  But there might need a little modification: your check logic of if a dir is a sub dir of another seems  not strict: [[ ! ( $i =~ $a ) ]] should be changed to [[ $i != $a/* ]] ?

Comment: Maybe  [[ $i != $a/* ]]  is better, indeed.

Comment: Finally, I have improved it to a more compact style: `find . -type d | while read d; do [[ $p && $d != $p/* ]] && echo $p; p=$d; done`, if you append this command to 
 your answer, I will mark your answer as `Accepted`. Do not worry about the variable contamination, the var in while part is running in a piped shell, its env will not affect current shell's env. For example, `x=xxx; echo yyy | while read x; do echo inside while the x is $x; done; echo out side the while the x is still $x`, the final x will still be xxx.

Comment: Well but what happened when p has a value? Ok, the subshell not change it...

Comment: And the (find . -type d;echo) echo need, because the last line lost instead.... (Maybe the EOF flag help...)

Comment: You are right. Changed to `find . -type d | (p=""; while read d; do [[ $p && $d != $p/* ]] && echo $p; p=$d; done)`.  But still lost the last line. So forget it. I will accept your answer

Comment: Found several solutions to eliminate the empty echo.  `find . -type d | sort -r | (p=""; while read d; do [[ $p != $d/* ]] && echo $d; p=$d; done)` or `find . -type d | tac | (p=""; while read d; do [[ $p != $d/* ]] && echo $d; p=$d; done)`, where `tac` is reverse `cat` which I am not sure if it is a standard utility.

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
has_subdirs() () (( $# )) ${1-$REPLY}/*(ND/Y1)
print -rC1 -- **/*(ND/^+has_subdirs)
```

Or directly without the intermediary function:

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(ND/^e['()(($#)) $REPLY/*(ND/Y1)'])
```

That's:

- `fn() some-command` defines a `fn` function with `some-command` as the body like in the Bourne-shell and most Bourne-like shells.
- `() { code } args` an anonymous function which runs `code` with `args` as the positional parameter.
- `(( $# ))` here the body of that anonymous function is an arithmetic expression which resolves to *true* if `$#` (the number of arguments) is non-zero.
- `${param-default}` (from the Bourne shell) expands to `$param` if the parameter is set or `default` otherwise. Here with `${1-$REPLY}`, we allow our function to be called directly (as `has_subdirs mydir`) or as a globbing qualifier function like below.
- `$dir/*(ND/Y1)` expands to the files of type directory in `$dir` (`/`) including hidden ones (`D`otglob), and don't error out if there's no match (`N`ullglob). But with `Y1`, we stop at the first match. So the anonymous function (and therefore `has_subdirs`) will return true if the directory contains at least one subdir.
- `print -rC1` prints its arguments `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn
- `^+has_subdirs` restricts to files for which the `has_subdirs` function does not (`^`) return true.

If you have to use the `bash` shell, just do:

```
zsh << 'EOF'
  print -rC1 -- **/*(ND/^e['()(($#)) $REPLY/*(ND/Y1)'])
EOF
```

Or to store the result in a bash array (needs bash-4.4+):

```
readarray -td '' array < <(zsh << 'EOF'
  print -rNC1 -- **/*(ND/^e['()(($#)) $REPLY/*(ND/Y1)'])
EOF
)
```

(using NUL-delimited records so as to be able to store arbitrary paths).

If you don't have `zsh`, but you have `perl`, you could do:

```
find . -depth -type d -print0 |
  perl -l -0ne 'print if rindex $prev, "$_/", 0; $prev = $_'
```

Or if you have GNU `awk`:

```
find . -depth -type d -print0 |
  gawk -v 'RS=\0' 'index(prev, $0"/") != 1; {prev = $0}'
```

Those have `find` print the directories *depth first* (leaves before the branches they're on) and gets `perl`/`awk` to print the records that are not found followed by `/` at the start of the previous record.

Again, to store the files in a bash 4.4+ array, you'd want to switch to NUL delimited records on output by moving the `-l` after `-0` in `perl` or add `-v 'ORS=\0'` in `gawk`:

```
readarray -td array < <(
  find . -depth -type d -print0 |
    perl -0lne 'print if rindex $prev, "$_/", 0; $prev = $_'
)
```

```
readarray -td array < <(
  find . -depth -type d -print0 |
    gawk -v 'RS=\0' -v 'ORS=\0' 'index(prev, $0"/") != 1; {prev = $0}'
)
```

On some systems and file systems (such as `ext4` filesystems on Linux-based systems), you may be able to rely on the fact that directories which have subdirs have a link count greater than 2 (`dir`, `dir/.` and an additional link for each `dir/subdir/..`).

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(ND/l-3)
```

Or using `find` in any shell:

```
find . -type d -links -3
```

That won't work on `btrfs` (which has replaced `ext4` as the default filesystems in several Linux distributions) for instance where the link count of directories is always one, so I wouldn't recommend that as a general solution.

Same for union filesystems as is your case, such as `overlayfs` where I find some *merged* directories have a link count of 1 whether they contain subdirectories or not.

However, wherever it's usable, if has the advantage over solutions that manually count the subdirs that you don't need read access to the directory (only search access to its parent).

Comment: @Quasímodo, if you're refering to the `find -links` one, as I said it's not portable as there are several filesystems on which that hack does work. That's why I said *on some systems and filesystems*. The `zsh` ones (other than the one using `l-3`) are the most portable ones as they don't rely on external utilities.

Comment: thank you for your detail and comprehensive answer. However neither is perfect, I prefer a bash-able one-line command(of course pipe is ok). It is interesting of the `-links <N>` option, but it is not a strict way, especially in a container, the dir may has extra hard links. Since it seems no prebuilt command to do this, I will consider using some awk or sort command to do it, let me think.

Comment: @osexp2003, on most systems, dirs can't have hardlinks other than the `.` and `..` created automatically by the system (for those FS where `.` and `..` are implemented as real directory entries).

Comment: Anyway, `-links <N>` can not handle arbitrary dir depth

Comment: @osexp2003, why would it not? That's not any more dependant on the depth than any other `find` predicate.

Comment: I have tested that -links 2 or -links 3 does not work. For example, `find /etc -type d -links 3` or `-links 2` results `./kernel`, `./kernel/postinst.d` ...

Comment: @osexp2003, that's `-links -3` (for files with a number of links strictly less than 3). There's no way both `find -links 2` and `find -links 3` can give you the same files though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130903/discussion-between-osexp2003-and-stephane-chazelas).

Comment: thank you for your patience, really learned from various answers, especially the `-links`. But I have really tried hard for all answers, `find /etc -type d -links 3` or `find /etc -type d -links 2` does not work for me(Just in a normal linux container). The only work method is `find . -type d -links 2 -noleaf`. BTW it is a Ubuntu Bionic container.

Comment: @osexp2003, that may be an artefact of the filesystem there likely being some sort of union file system where the link count is not reliable. An illustration of why I'd recommand not to use it in the general case. I'd expect the solutions I gave that don't use the link count (I've added a few more) should work well there.

Comment: You are right! I have tested `-links 2` works in a normal container `docker run -it --rm ubuntu:bionic find /etc -type d -links 2` works, but in my case, I mount a dir from host into the container, that is the issue!

Answer (score 2):

What you looking for is:

```
find . -type d -links 2
```

Each directory in filesystem has at least two hard links - the directory itself in the parent and '.' entry.
Each '..' entry in the subdirs add a new hard link to the directory. So you just need to find directories with two hard links.

The command suggested in another answer

```
find . -type d -links -3
```

Does the same, but with a statement "directories with less than three hard links to it."

Comment: That's only true on some historic filesystems. That's not true on btrfs for instance which is the default FS on several Linux distributions these days. So, I wouldn't advise it in the general case. I'm not sure what that answer adds compared to mine as I already offered that solution (and pointed out its limitation).

Comment: Yes, it wont work on a FS without hard links.

Comment: It's not about the FS supporting hard links, it's about how `.` and `..` are implemented. btrfs does support hard links but doesn't implement `.` and `..` as hard links. `.` and `..` as directory entries is just a historical artefact from the original Unix filesystem implementation.

Comment: normally this works, but it is not reliable, who knows the dir are hard linked by more than 3? I have even found `-links 10` shows a match, this happens in a overlayfs.

Answer (score 0):

Read `man find`. The `-mindepth` option is what you want.